# How to test PasswordChangeView in Django?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm trying to create a test for the `get_success_url` method of PasswordChangeView to see whether the redirect work as intended.

The expected behavior I'm looking for -- with a valid form -- is to have the password changed, and to get a 302 redirect response.

But for some unknown reason, I can't seem to pass valid form data, so I get a 200 response, and the test keeps failing.

Does anyone know why the test below gives me an invalid form? What am I missing?

## test.py

```py
def test_success_url(self):
    client = Client()
    user = User.objects.create(username="anon", password="pw")
    client.force_login(user)
    data = {
      'old_password': 'pw',
      'new_password1': 'newpw',
      'new_password2': 'newpw',
    }
    response = client.post('/anon/change-password/', data)
    user.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertTrue(user.check_password('newpw))
    self.assertEqual(response, 302)
```

## views.py

```py
class UserPasswordChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionMixin, PasswordChangeView):

  def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse("user:detail", kwargs={ "username": self.request.user })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `create_user` to create your user object, not `create`.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username="anon", password="pw")
```